# Combining 2 measured in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have 5 segments and 5 products with in 1st segment. I have 2 measures, first measure calculate % sales contribution of each segment and second measure calculate % sales contribution of each product within the first segment. Now I want to create one measure which will help me to display % contribution of that segment and % contribution of each product within that segment using a single measure. Can anyone help me out here?

Present: -

```
SEGMENT  % SALES BY BRAND    % SALES BY SEGMENT
CEREAL       100%                    8%
PROD1        25%                     2.08%
PROD2        22%                     1.85%
PROD3        21%                     1.15%
PROD4        18%                     1.6%
PROD5        14%                     1.32%
```

Expected : -

```
SEGMENT % SALES BY BRAND   
CEREAL       8%                    
PROD1        25%                     
PROD2        22%                     
PROD3        21%                     
PROD4        18%                     
PROD5        14%
```

Answer (score 0):

The following measure checks if the `% SALES BY BRAND` measure returns a blank value and if the `% SALES BY BRAND` measure is blank (which it should be for non-product rows like "CEREAL"), then it returns the value from `% SALES BY SEGMENT`.
Otherwise, if the `% SALES BY BRAND` measure is not blank (which should be the case for product rows like "PROD1", "PROD2", etc.), then it simply returns the value from `% SALES BY BRAND`:

```
Combined % Contribution :=
IF(
    ISBLANK([% SALES BY BRAND]),
    [% SALES BY SEGMENT],
    [% SALES BY BRAND]
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve it using ISINSCOPE DAX FUNCTION, I MODIFIED MY DAX LIKE THE BELOW AND IT GAVE ME THE ANSWER : -

SWITCH (TRUE(),
ISINSCOPE('Table Name'[Brand]),
DIVIDE(SUM('Table Name'[Sales]), CALCULATE(SUM('Table Name'[Sales]), ALLSELECTED('Table Name'[Brand]))),
ISINSCOPE('Table Name'[Segment]),
DIVIDE(SUM('Table Name'[Sales]), CALCULATE(SUM('Table Name'[Sales]), ALLSELECTED('Table Name'[Segment]))),,
1
)